# How to fix `error getting Lambda Function code signing config AccessDeniedException` Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, code-signing, terraform-provider-aws

I defined a Lambda resource in Terraform, but I encountered error below:

```
error getting Lambda Function (xxxx) code signing config AccessDeniedException
```

After some googling, I found that I can temporary fix this by specifying AWS provider version <= 3.16.0,this fixed the error temporary but the version is too low, it doesn't support 'using ECR image for lambda', the Terraform version I'm currently using is `v0.13.4`.

[This page](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16398) claims that AWS provider version 3.18.0 works, but I still get this error is I don't specify AWS provider to 3.16.0.
Can someone help with this please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this issue [resource/aws_lambda_function - possible regression w/3.17.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16755) similar error.

You need to amend the policy like

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:GetCodeSigningConfig",
                         
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a specific reason you are using Terraform version `0.13.4` with that old provider?

You can share your terraform config as well with error with the [DEBUG](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html) flag on terraform apply

Comment: Do you mean adding this permission in the Lambda role or the AWS role I'm performing? I tried to add this in my lambda role but still getting the same error.

Comment: `Terraform version 0.13.4` is only because I haven't updated my terraform, but the `provider version` I had to set to `<=3.16.0` otherwise I'll get this `code signing error`, but I'd love to be able to use the latest `provider version`, I just can't get rid of this error message..

Comment: @Cecilia can you add allow policy to the user who is doing the apply. To me it works even after denying the `codesigning`. You can see my example [here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/625530d6a6ae82671461039b7bc41082). As I requested in the question share your code snippet with debug output. Problem might be somewhere else too.

Comment: When I set `required_providers {aws = {source = "hashicorp/aws" version = "3.16.0"}` it works fine (like in your example), what I meant in this question is that I'll get the `codesigningerror` without specifying provider version to 3.16.0. So if I use 3.18.0, this error will show up.

Comment: It worked for `3.18.0` version as well, I updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/625530d6a6ae82671461039b7bc41082). Is it possible for you to do `terraform init` with the provider version changed?

Comment: turns out it's the AWS role I'm using, it needs the `codesigning` permission, thanks @samtoddler

Comment: This is an issue once more, see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16755