# AccessDeniedException for user with AdministratorAccess on eu-central-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have simple tutorial-level code for creating IAM Policy and Lambda.

Everything works fine on eu-central-1, but when I try to use eu-central-2 (Zürich):

1. both policy and lambda are created
2. Terraform is trying to get Code Signing Config (?):

```
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response lambda/GetFunctionCodeSigningConfig Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/2.0 403 Forbidden
X-Amzn-Errortype: AccessDeniedException
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response lambda/GetFunctionCodeSigningConfig failed, attempt 0/25, error AccessDeniedException:
status code: 403, request id: xxxx
[DEBUG] Unlocking "aws_lambda_function"
[DEBUG] Unlocked "aws_lambda_function"

Response contains error diagnostic: diagnostic_detail= tf_proto_version=5.3 diagnostic_summary="error getting Lambda Function (test_lambda) code signing config AccessDeniedException:
    status code: 403, request id: xxx" tf_provider_addr=registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws tf_req_id=9c3edc87-a488-26bc-cee0-f8b0289a6c22 tf_resource_type=aws_lambda_function @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.1/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_severity=ERROR tf_rpc=ApplyResourceChange timestamp=2022-11-23T18:23:31.673+0100
2022-11-23T18:23:31.682+0100 [ERROR] vertex "aws_lambda_function.hello_world" error: error getting Lambda Function (test_lambda) code signing config AccessDeniedException:
    status code: 403, request id: xxx
```

The user is in the Group AdministratorAccess, which I assume should have access to all information. I tried adding AWSLambda_FullAccess or explicitly:

```
"lambda:UpdateCodeSigningConfig",
"lambda:GetFunctionEventInvokeConfig",
"lambda:GetCodeSigningConfig",
"lambda:CreateCodeSigningConfig",
"lambda:GetFunctionCodeSigningConfig"
```

and there's no difference.

Comment: I see that similar situation has happened before with different regions. I submitted a bug : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/27986

Comment: Have you enabled that region for that particular AWS account?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, otherwise the lambda would not be created in the first place.

Comment: Ah, my bad, not my day today. :) Does this answer maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797662/8343484?

Comment: @MarkoE unfortunately not, I tried that one (as described in the question).
The issue here is that eu-central-2 does not support AWS Signer which is used by Terraform to check if lambda code has been modified (described in the bug I submitted).

The only thing that could help me, temporarily, would be to find a way to skip code signing check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a bug in Terraform. It got solved in 4.42.0:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/28008

If you found this question and see the same error message, please make sure that your region is on the list of support for AWS Signer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signer.html

As Terraform is leveraging this service, regions that do not support it need to be added to a special list before they'll work correctly. You'll need to file a bug on Github for it.